# Find the maximum and minimum values of of f(x,y,z) with the following constraints

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Find the maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y,z) = x^3 -3y^2 + 4z$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y,z)=x + yz - 4 = 0$.

So far I've plugged this into Mathematica and it returned 6 complex conjugate coordinates and one real
$(4.00087, 0.0832872,-0.0104076)$.

I did a bit of manipulation of the constraint and found a second point $(4.00087, -0.0832872, 0.0104076)$ but when I evaluated both the values differed by less than 1.

Does this indicate that the function has no extreme values given the constraint?

Comment: No, it means that there more than one solutions for the given constraints. You have to choose the global minimum if you want the answer (minimum of all the local minimum values)

Comment: Could you go into more detail? Do I choose the smallest of the values I got for the above points as my global minimum?

Comment: Exactly. Choose the point which gives the lowest for $f$ value in amongst the various points you calculated as minima

Comment: hmph. I suppose I should've trusted myself more. I only computed the 2 points above. The first gave me 63.9793 and the latter 64.0626. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I would also like to point out that a similar approach would be used for the maximum value calculation. It's up to you to check whether the given point (which you obtain) is for maxima or minima (using any technique you know). It Is quite possible that 63.97 might be the min and 64.0.. would be the max value (I am just throwing out here, checking it in the function is up to you)  :)

Comment: A) I'm guessing that you're just learning about Lagrange Multipliers? If so, refer back to your source to understand how to continue. B) Note that the 2 points you calculated are most likely the same point of (4,0,0) with slight rounding error

Comment: You'll have to forgive my ignorance (self taught about this topic), when you say "for the maximum value calculation", I interpret it as separate. My understanding is that I used Lagrange Multiplier to find a set of points that satisfy the constraint and then evaluate them in the function and categorize them from there.

Comment: @CalvinLin, A) I'm self taught learning from yt videos and my own textbook. They don't really bring up the situation I'm referring to in my original question.
 
B) Thank you! That was issue I was concerned about, because the values were so close to each other. In that case I'm back to where I started though. :/

Comment: On another note, I tried attempting this in Wolfram online and it tells me there is no maximum and minimum given the constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is unbounded below and above. If you set $x=4$ and $y=0$, any $z$ satisfies the constraints while the objective function is $64+4z$.

Comment: Ok I understand your reasoning. So where do we go from there?

Comment: @Malcolm you see that the function is unbounded by taking $z$ very small or very large, right? So that answers the question.

Comment: From what I understand there is no maximum or minimum given the constraint.